# Use of # for commands in Tcl

Tags: tcl, comments

I am using sentaurus TCAD for semiconductors device simulations and I have encountered something I can't understand in the .cmd files (the scripts in tcl that gets executed from specific tools) related to the use of '#'.

As everyone knows '#' is used to leave a comment in tcl. If you put '#' at the start of the line, everything you type until either ';' or the newline character will be commented out. For example:

```
#This is a comment and everything on this line is treated as such.
puts "Hello world" ; #This is a comment and everything after right of ';' is treated as such on this line.
```

What I found in the scripts is a peculiar way to express the if-else statement:

```
#if <condition>

<commands>

#else

<commands>

#endif
```

I substituted to that block the usual tcl if-else statement:

```
if {<condition>} {
   <commands>
} else {
   <commands>
}
```

And of course it still works but I was left wondering, why is that the interpreter does not consider #if as a comment? Where does the #if #else #endif syntax come from? I don't find any documentation online about it, only the usual syntax is reported.

Comment: Isn't this a [preprocessor](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Main/TCADSentaurus) syntax? So, syntax preprocessing before Tcl comes into play?

Comment: If plain Tcl ran that, you would execute both the "true" and "false" commands.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, that is what I thought as well but It is not the case. It follows that this is not plain Tcl, even though the manual says It is.

Comment: @mrcalvin I looked It up and found a second manual related to the workbench itself of Sentaurus and It is indeed preprocessor syntax. But what is this for? Why there two different sets of syntax on the same script? Why not using just Tcl? This is incredibly confusing to me. Maybe I should change the question to specifically refer to Sentaurus since this is not strictly related to Tcl?

Answer (score 2):

If the Tcl parser sees a `#` *when it is looking for the first character of the first word of a command* (or in an extended-format regular expression, or at many points inside an expression from 8.7/9.0 onwards), then from that point to the end of the line is a comment. Note that in the body of a command like `proc` the Tcl parser is *not* looking for a command, at least not when the procedure is defined; it only looks when the procedure is evaluated (or rather when it is compiled to bytecode, typically immediately before entering on the first call). The bracket matcher is stupid, but a fundamental part of how Tcl works; parsing is conceptually very late (but earlier in practice for most code). Indeed, the whole parser is very simple; the commands we supply are all just a standard library.

This means that `#` really is a proper comment syntactic form, but you probably need to balance brackets in it anyway, at least at the level of a whole containing thing like `proc`. It is a good habit to do it everywhere.

This works:

```
# if {$code == 1
puts "I'm printing this anyway"
```

As does this:

```
proc foo args {
    # if {$code == 1} {
    puts "I'm printing this anyway"
    # }
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
proc foo args {
    # if {$code == 1
    puts "I'm printing this anyway"
}
```

And this won't do what you expect...

```
proc foo args {
    # if {$code == 1
    puts "I'm printing this anyway"
}
# }
```

You can predict this by simply counting the number of outstanding bracket pairs. No more complex notion required.

And this works... but is weird.

```
proc foo args "
    # if {\$code == 1
    puts \"I'm printing this anyway\"
"
# }
```

Comment: Don't do that last form unreal code. It is legal... but *awful!*